# Pass a template function a non-template type?

Tags: c++, templates, set

```
template <class T, class Compare = std::less<T>>
class Test
{
    protected:
        std::set<T, Compare> s;
    public:
        Test(std::set<T, Compare>&);
        void add(const std::set<T, Compare>&);
}

template <class T, class Compare>
Test<T, Compare>::Test(std::set<T, Compare>& t)
{
    s = t;
}

template <class T, class Compare>
void Test<T, Compare>::add(const std::set<T, Compare>& t)
{
    typename std::set<T, Compare>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = t.begin(); itr != t.end(); itr++)
    {
        s.insert(*itr);
    }
}
```

I have the following setup:

```
std::set<int, std::less<int>> s;
std::set<int, std::greater<int>> si;
s.insert(3);
si.insert(5);

Test<int> a(s);
a.add(si)
```

Now I see why the compiler throws: no matching function for call to 'Test::add(std::set<int, std::greater >&)' a.set_union(si)

But can I make it work somehow?

Answer (score 5):

The **problem** is that `s` is of type `std::set<int, std::less<int>>`  and thus the parameter of `add` is a `const std::set<int, std::less<int>>&` while the argument `si` that you're passing is of type `std::set<int, std::greater<int>>`.

One way to solve this is to make `add` a **member function template** as shown below:

```
template <class T, class Compare = std::less<T>>
class Test
{
    protected:
        std::set<T, Compare> s;
    public:
        Test(std::set<T, Compare>&);
        //declaration of member function template add
        template<typename SecCompare>
        void add(const std::set<T, SecCompare>&);
};

template <class T, class Compare>
Test<T, Compare>::Test(std::set<T, Compare>& t)
{
    s = t;
}

//implementation of member function template add
template <class T, class Compare>
template<typename SecCompare>
void Test<T, Compare>::add(const std::set<T, SecCompare>& t)
{
    typename std::set<T, Compare>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = t.begin(); itr != t.end(); itr++)
    {
        s.insert(*itr);
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/lE8F9h_Ag).

Comment: @Anoop Rana I would have another question, if its okey.
Test<int> a(s) isn't working for me, but Test<int, std::less<int>> a(s) is. So I think it's because I have 6.3 gcc version and it's not supporting c++17. I just looking for clarification

Comment: @Wooknows Yes 6.3 is really old. It has decent support for c++14. Your g++ version should sit at the 11 version.

Comment: @Wooknows The program works even in C++11 and gcc 5.5.0. See [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IkaMqp3oZWZuly6Q). To confirm this and that the error is not due to a typo try copy/pasting the code from [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IkaMqp3oZWZuly6Q) and compiling it with your g++ 6.3 version and you'll see that it works without any problem. Note that we don't need C++17 for this. C++11 is enough for this.